# Properties of an entity in a different entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle to manage the users and the security. I also have a different table that carries all the metadata of the user, like the profile picture, facebook id, etc.

I need to tell FOSUserBundle that instead of getting the username and the email from the user entity, it has to go to a different entity 'UserMeta', making a query to retrieve all the user metadata and take only the one that have a typeMeta equals to name.

something like:

```
public function getUsername(){
    $metas = $this->getMetas();
    foreach($metas as $meta){
        if($meta->getTypeMeta() == '_name'){
        return $meta->getContent();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need to tell FOSUserBundle that instead of getting the username and the email from the user entity, it has to go to a different entity 'UserMeta', making a query to retrieve all the user metadata and take only the one that have a typeMeta equals to name.

Comment: But it have to work for login, logout, register, profile, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option using the FOSUserBundle would be to use a custom storage layer.

Your code would go as follow:

```
abstract class CustomUser implements UserInterface
{
  public function getUsername(){
      $metas = $this->getMetas();
      foreach($metas as $meta){
          if($meta->getTypeMeta() == '_name'){
          return $meta->getContent();
          }
      }
      return null;
  }
  //....
}
```

And in your `config.yml`:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: custom
    user_class: Acme\YourBundle\Model\CustomUser
    service:
        user_manager: acme_user.custom_manager
    firewall_name: main
```

Full documentation available here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/custom_storage_layer.md